# Upgrade gmail account to buisness account

Tags: email, gmail

I have a gmail account with custom domain.
I want to add some more account to this domain,
In order to do that i need to upgrade my account to buisness account (Dont i?)

How do i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at Google Apps for Businesses [here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/)